# Are some achievements only attainable in single player?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

After trying to get "Till Death Do Us Part" three times in a co-op game (which failed all 3 times) and then getting it instantly when trying it in a single player game I'm wondering if there are any other achievements that you can only get in single player games? (I'm suspecting "Pink'd" to be one of them)

Comment: I'll confirm that "Pink'd" appears to track the *killing blow*.  This is easiest earned in single player with no follower, because of the chance your follower/teammates might score the last hit.  I'm assuming "I just Blue myself" is the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received "Til Death Do Us Part" in multiplayer, but neither of the two members in my party did.  The reason has become clear in the patch 1.0.2 notes.

> All players in a party should now receive "Till Death Do Us Part" even if they don’t have Haedrig Eamon as their active follower

I suspect that any other achievements that seem difficult in a group are not on purpose (barring the follower achievements obviously), and are bugged.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't comment on the specific achievements that you've mentioned, some notable examples of achievements that can only be earned in single-player play are those that require you to have a Follower active, such as [I'll Be Your Wingman](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/ill-be-your-wingman).

Comment: As Blizzard would put it - "very creative way of answering the question" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Certain conversation options for achievements are only available if the character is following you.

I had a hard time getting a few of Leah's conversations (in act 1) because I was always playing in a group.